# How to save this number 103636927986606774863 in any numeric format in mysql

Tags: mysql

I got an error when i trying to save this number, I have referred [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html) 
But need know any other options to save a number which value is grater than 9223372036854775807.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to save this as `varchar()` since its beyond the limit of int and bigint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store it using a datatype called  `numeric`

below is the workaround solution

```
You can store it as numeric(21,0) // 21 is the limit of number of digits
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample mysql query

Comment: This is what i tried "UPDATE  `nativerank_main`.`userMyBusiness` SET  `b` =  '103636927986606774863' WHERE  `userMyBusiness`.`id` =9;"

But it shows "Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'b' at row 1"

Comment: @sijovijayan your column type should of `numeric` type

Comment: @sijovijayan use this query first than try to update it `alter table nativerank_main modify column_name numeric(21,0)`

Comment: Thanks, Now i can save the values